# Mobaxterm: how to keep sftp connection alive?

Tags: ssh, sftp, mobaxterm

I kept ssh connection alive following this post:
[Mobaxterm: how to prevent ssh session from exiting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57385896/mobaxterm-how-to-prevent-ssh-session-from-exiting)

I managed to keep ssh connection alive but sftp connection on the left panel keeps disconnecting after a certain time while ssh is still alive and I have to every time reconnect the sftp. Sometimes, reconnect button on the left panel doesn't even work and I have to exit the shell and restart the ssh session again. What I want to achieve here is to keep the sftp connection (graphical browser on the left panel) alive in addition to ssh. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, then I asked MobaXterm support and they gave me this answer:
You should update the SSH browser type to "SCP enhanced speed" mode. For this you can go to the settings of your SSH session, go to the advanced SSH settings and in the SSH browser type drop list choose SCP (enhanced speed).